# load chain payment url to web view

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, uiwebviewdelegate

In my application I want to use chain payment , as paypal ios sdk doesn't  support chain payment I am involving back end to this functionality.  Now in back end side they are giving me one url which I need to load in web view . This url is of chain payment , user will login to paypal from that url and will do transaction. But then after completion of transaction I need to close that web view. How to detect that transaction is completed in web view?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you controller as a UIWebViewDelegate and implement this method :

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    NSString *url = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    if ([url isEqualToString:@"your confirmation page URL"]) {

        // dismiss the view controller or navigate to a beautiful confirmation view
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes you have a webView property on your view controller that points to you UIWebView.

Comment: means..in back end I need to set return url in paypal?? And then I have to check if web view has load that url then close that web view?

Comment: Yes you can do it like that.

Comment: ok gr8...I was thinking same....but doing it first time so I thought may be possible better way then this....thank you